# How to correctly unsubscribe from a socket.io room and destroy it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an internal loop for each socket:

```
if (!chat.room.list[hash]) { // room has expired
    socket.leave(hash);
    delete chat.user.list[socket.store.data.id].rooms[hash];
    delete socket.store.data.inRooms[hash]; // delete room hash from user store
}
```

`socket.leave(hash)` does nothing - socket still receives messages sent to `hash` room.

As a side note - if I connect with client Anna and client Bob - both receive messages, but if I reconnect with client Bob - Bob cannot send messages to Anna.

Is there somewhere a full socket io API documentation (as I couldn't find socket.leave(room) examples)?

EDIT:
Got it! Socket IO saves room handles with slash, so you have to use `socket.leave('/'+hash)`

Comment: You should add your solution as an 'answer' so this doesn't come up as 'unanswered'

Answer (score 7):

Rooms in socket.io are implicitly created and implicitly deleted. Basically they are automatically removed when they are empty.

And yes, a preceding `/` is added to the rooms name internally but you do **not** need to add this to remove a socket from a room.

Try firing `console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms)` whenever a room is created to have a look at what's happening internally.

Comment: what's the best way to debug why room leaves might not be happening? ie. rooms stay populated even when clients disconnect. using a redisstore.

Answer (score 3):

As of 0.8.7 i tried it out and it seems you don't have to add the / (slash) anymore

```
socket.leave(hash)
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

SocketIO 1.0 has `Socket.prototype.leave(roomName)` and `Socket.prototype.leaveAll()`.

And you don't have to manually remove rooms:

> Upon disconnection, sockets leave all the channels they were part of automatically, and no specially teardown is needed on your part. [[From here]](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Answer (score -1):

Sort of a tangent, but to answer the part of your question about a full socket.io documentation:  Not quite, however, if you check out the source on [socket.io's home page](http://socket.io) you can find some sparse documentation  (view the source and CTRL+F for "rooms").  I've had to do this several times already.  There's nothing about leaving rooms there, but there is some general explanation.

view-source:http://socket.io