# how to delete a room in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to statically remove all users from a room, effectively deleting that room. The idea is that another room with the same name may be created again in the future, but I want it created empty (without the listeners from the previous room).

I'm not interested in managing the room status myself but rather curious as if I can leverage socket.io internals to do this. Is this possible? (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228730/how-to-correctly-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-room-and-destroy-it))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
io.sockets.clients(someRoom).forEach(function(s){
    s.leave(someRoom);
});
```

Comment: Can't check right now but this might work too : `io.sockets.in(someRoom).leave(someRoom)`

Comment: @DenysSéguret io.sockets.in(room).leave(room) it throws an error saying `io.sockets.in(...).leave is not a function`. And the above solution also doesn't work. That one also throwing an error `io.sockets.clients(...).forEach is not a function`

Answer (score 17):

For an up-to-date answer to this question, everyone who wants to remove a room can make use of `Namespace.clients(cb)`. The `cb` callback will receive an error object as the first argument (`null` if no error) and a list of socket IDs as the second argument.

It should work fine with `socket.io` `v2.1.0`, not sure which version is the earliest compatible one.

```
io.of('/').in('chat').clients((error, socketIds) => {
  if (error) throw error;

  socketIds.forEach(socketId => io.sockets.sockets[socketId].leave('chat'));

});
```

@See https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3042
@See https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-clients-callback

Comment: Works for me in 2.2.0.

Comment: What if using a cluster with redis-adapter, does the io.sockets.sockets[socketId] is available in all processes?

Comment: This worked for me while the answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using socket io v4 or greater you can use this:

```
io.in("room1").socketsLeave("room1");

//all the clients in room1 will leave romm1
//hence deleting the room automatically
//as there are no more active users in it
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, it's worth mentioning that...

> Upon disconnection, sockets leave all the channels they were part of
>   automatically, and no special teardown is needed on your part.

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ (Disconnection)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem described - ie. how can these users/sockets be removed in the first place? If you're simply interested in adding some useful information, perhaps that would be worthwhile just as a comment?

Comment: "The idea is that another room with the same name may be created again in the future, but I want it created empty..." And then read what I quoted from the documentation. When a socket disconnects, it leaves all the channels automatically, so there's no need for teardown. I see no reason for your downvote. Sorry but your argument doesn't really make sense for me. Perhaps I misunderstood? :)

Comment: @JakubDuchon, thank you for your contribution to this question. Your answer helps me :) and anyone who thinks they may have to manually manage a room's deletion.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto ROCK ON's answer for for version 4.X. If you need to do more than just leave the room, you can do:

```
const sockets = await io.in(room).fetchSockets();
sockets.forEach(s => {
  // Do stuff
  s.emit('host disconnected', room);
  s.leave(room);
});
```