# Socket.IO delete a room by name

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there any way to delete a room completely when it's not needed anymore by its name.
I have tried following answer but it's not working:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23342511
I am using socketio 2 and it's throwing the following error:

```
node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:210
```

`if (fn) process.nextTick(fn.bind(null, null, sids)); TypeError: fn.bind is not a function`

Basically, is there any shortcut for deleting/removing the room instead of performing `leave` for each socket?

Comment: I don't think socket.io have to implement this, it wouldn't know what names can not be used anymore. I'll suggest manage names by self, using Redis or whatever to cache the valid names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here how I finally solved the issue:

```
io.of('/').in('room name').clients(function(error, clients) {
    if (clients.length > 0) {
        console.log('clients in the room: \n');
        console.log(clients);
        clients.forEach(function (socket_id) {
            io.sockets.sockets[socket_id].leave('room name');
        });
    }
});
```

This should work with socket.IO version 2.x